# How to load a default page in an iframe if the intended cross-domain src is 404?

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

I have a javascript script, hosted on my server, that is getting added to sites I do not host through a `<script src="http://myserver/myscript.js">` tag.  When those sites are opened, the script will launch a modal box that opens a page I DO host in an iframe.

I know this sounds shady but the people who own these sites are paying for this.  It really is legit.

I may have up to 5 different pages for a given client. The query string determines which page loads in the iframe.

I want to include a default page (a different default for each client) to load in case the query string variable doesn't match up with any of the pages I have for them.

I can check for LACK of a variable on the query string and open the default in that case.  But what if the page loaded in the iframe is a 404?  How can I load the default in that case?

I've read through all the posts I can find relating to this.  I understand that cross-domain security risks mean that this is not supported by Javascript.  But some posts mentioned there might be ways to achieve it using PHP in addition to Javascript.  What are some of the workarounds?

I can not include any libraries on the external site.  I can only place the single `<script>` tag on the external site.

I'm using plain, vanilla javascript for everything (since I can't include a jquery library on the external site), and it's all in a single file right now.

If I were to use additional files, I'm not sure how the files would all work together.  I'd need help with that, too.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for the PostMessage API:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

This will allow message passing between external Javascript (the script your clients append to their website) and your (OWNED) iFrame contents. Scripts inside the iFrame can listen for posted messages from above, and vice versa.

With this, you can set your client script to listen for a message from iFrame, such as `{loaded: true}`, and take action if it happens (or doesn't happen). If the iFrame does not reply to the client script's request within some set amount of seconds, then you can reasonably believe that page 404'd.

Comment: This looks very promising.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Could you use:

```
iframeElement.onerror = function(){
  // do stuff
}
```

?

It won't work in older Browsers, though.